# boost::archive_exception causes unhandled exception within VisualStudio2012

Tags: c++, unhandled-exception, boost-serialization

A `boost::archive_exception` is confounding me. The exception details are as follows

```
Unhandled exception: boost::archive::archive_exception at memory location...
```

This occurs when attempting the following `boost::serialization` load operation that essentially works when `BinarySearchTree<std::string>` but not when `BinarySearchTree<int>`

```
typedef boost::variant<BinarySearchTree<std::string>, BinarySearchTree<int>> BinarySearchTreeVariant;

BinarySearchTreeVariant search_tree_;

BinarySearchTree<std::string> string_search_tree_;
BinarySearchTree<int> int_search_tree_;

boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTree<std::string>> binary_string_search_tree_;
boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTree<int>> binary_int_search_tree_;    

search_tree_ = int_search_tree_;

binary_int_search_tree_.reset(new BinarySearchTree<int>());

try{

    if(!binary_int_search_tree_->load(binary_int_search_tree_, search_tree_name))
        throw CustomException("Load of binary search tree to disk fail");

    }
    catch(CustomException &custom_exception){ }
```

The code that defines `load` is as follows

```
bool load(boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTree> &tree, const std::string &search_tree_file_name)
{
    // create and open an archive for output
    std::ifstream reader(search_tree_file_name);

    if(reader){
        boost::archive::text_iarchive serial_reader(reader);
        // read class state from archive
        serial_reader >> *tree;    <<<--- Unhandled Exception
        // archive and stream closed when destructors are called

    }else if(reader.fail()){
        reader.clear();
    }

    return true;
}
```

My `search tree` is defined with `boost::serialization` as follows

```
class BinarySearchTree{

private:

    class BinarySearchTreeNode{

    public:

        friend class BinarySearchTree;

    private:

        friend class boost::serialization::access;
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int /* file_version */){
            archive & key;
            archive & index;
            archive & left;
            archive & right;
        }

        T key;
        long index;

        boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTreeNode> left;
        boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTreeNode> right;

    };  // End Tree Node Class Definition

    boost::shared_ptr<BinarySearchTreeNode> root;

    friend class boost::serialization::access;
    template <class Archive>
    void serialize(Archive &archive, const unsigned int version){
        archive & root;
    }
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you need `std::ios::binary` in your ifstream mode? It's also possible that you haven't *written* the archive correctly (it might be truncated?).

Comment: I am using `text_iarchive` in the `boost::serialization` definition.  Why would I need `std::ios::binary`?

Comment: Catch the exception and see `what()` it says?

Comment: I caught the exception using `try { serial_reader >> *tree; } catch (std::exception &e) {std::cout << e.what() << std::endl; }` and it specifies `input stream error`.  The `reader` in the `load` definition is valid allowing the exception to propagate.  How can the `boost::archive::text::iarchive` be invalid?

Comment: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/serialization/doc/exceptions.html#input_stream_error might help

Comment: @Oktalist I switched to `binary_oarchive` in an attempt to avoid the apparent problem with text archives noted in the doc you linked.  I am now getting an entirely different error about a vector subscript out of range.  However, I believe I need to destroy the `oarchive` prior to using the `iarchive` even though I performed a `save - load - save` cycle a number of times successfully prior to a `load` breaking down the serialization and causing exception to be thrown.

Comment: I discovered that avoiding the mixture throughout the program of `std::unique_ptr`, `std::shared_ptr`, and `boost::serialization` appears to produce undesirable results.  I have thus moved all dynamic memory to `boost::shared_ptr` and this appears has corrected my difficulty.